# Where is impala data storage allocated ?

Tags: cloudera-cdh, impala

Is there any designated directory for impala to store data in case the table is entirely managed by impala?

Or it is up to datanode to allocate the data to anywhere in HDFS configured by datanode directory such as /dfs/dn?

In case my app is running a node that is not running datanode, is it best practice that I should have an impalad running?  So that I can connect to impala anywhwere just using localhost? Otherwise I will have connect to a specific host and port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tables managed by Impala, data is stored in the Hive metastore warehouse directory which is configured by the Hive metastore configuration property 'hive.metastore.warehouse.dir' in hive-site.xml. This is a directory in HDFS, so the underlying storage locations across the datanodes is determined by the HDFS configuration.

You should run Impala daemons on nodes that have datanodes running so that the scans can be co-located with the data. Your app should connect to a remote Impala daemon. Distributing requests around the cluster is often a good idea or even necessary depending on the workload to avoid a bottleneck on a single coordinator impalad. Many people use HAProxy to do this, see [this documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/impala_proxy.html) for details.

Comment: In case my node doesn't run datanode (as it doens't provide hdfs storage), should impalad not be running my node? If so, how do I determine which host to connect to for impala in case there are 500 hosts where datanodes and impalad are all running on the same host? Should I use round robin? Does it mean my node will just install impala but not running impalad?

Comment: That's right. You should run Impala daemons only on the nodes that have datanodes. Distributing requests around the cluster is often a good idea or even necessary depending on the workload to avoid a bottleneck on a single coordinator impalad. Many people use HAProxy to do this: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/v5-2-x/topics/impala_proxy.html